# CSS - Bootstrap? / overflow: visible doesn't work in iOS

Tags: html, css, iphone, frontend, bootstrap-5

first post here.

I'm struggling in a Bootstrap site I'm building.
On my homepage I have a row with 8 columns, each one with PNGs inside - on mobile it shows only 4.
To avoid cutting out the images I've used the `overflow: visible` property in the CSS but I'm not even sure if it's the correct way of proceeding.

**On iOS on both Chrome and Safari this doesn't work** - I cannot find anything online to achieve the same goal but to make it work with every browser, and I'm really struggling now.

Do you guys have an idea if I'm doing everything correctly - or maybe the way I've set these columns are wrong from the beginning?

Here's the code that i've more or less written:

HTML:

```
<div class="row bckgrAlpha" id="playersPanel">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center playersTab">
        <!-- player1 -->
        <div class="col justify-content-center player1">
            <img src="something.png" class="players">
        </div>
        <!-- player2 -->
        <div class="col justify-content-center player2">
            <img src="something.png" class="players">
        </div>
        <!-- player3 -->
        <div class="col justify-content-center player3">
            <img src="something.png" class="players">
        </div>
        <!-- player4 -->
        <div class="col justify-content-center player4">
            <img src="something.png" class="players">
        </div>
        <!-- player5 -->
        <div class="col justify-content-center player5">
            <img src="something.png" class="players">
        </div>
        [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.players {
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    overflow: visible!important;
}
```

the columns player1 / player2 / player3 [...] are all working correctly but the images ***only on iPhone*** look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4k8T.png)

*Here's what I see from my pc/on my Android phone:*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfePW.png)